# javafx converting a polygon to an area

Tags: java, javafx

I recently wanted to create an Area (`com.sun.javafx.geom.Area`) from a polygon I already have (`javafx.scene.shape.Polygon`). The polygon itself would work, but the area says I should "cast polygon to PathIterator". But when I do so, an exception shows up that the class can not be cast to PathIterator 
(*j`ava.lang.ClassCastException: javafx.scene.shape.Polygon` cannot be cast to `com.sun.javafx.geom.PathIterator`*)

My question now is: According to the javadoc, the constructor of the Area-class should be able to take a Shape-object, which Polygon is (it extends Shape).
How do I correctly initialize an Area-object?

Comment: Why do you want to create an Area? It doesn't even show up in the api, plus it is in the sun packages. You definitely shouldn't cast Polygon to a PathIterator. Can you link the javadocs for Area?

Comment: `com.sun.javafx.geom.Shape` != `javafx.scene.shape.Shape`.

Comment: `com.sun.javafx` classes such as `com.sun.javafx.geom.Area` are unsupported internal API used for the JavaFX implementation.  Use of them by general application code is not recommended.

Comment: Hello all, thanks for your answers. I wanted to create an Area because i have to add and subtract polygons a lot and i saw in another answer that this would be the most suitable class to do so (because it's very tedious with just the Polygon-class I think).
But apparently I shouldn't use classes from that package at all like jewelsea stated, so I guess I'll have to search for something else.
Nevertheless, thanks for the quick help

Comment: @fabian you're right, I made a mistake in believing there is only one Shape-class for javafx and one for swing, but apparently there's also the com.sun one. I should have realized these are not compatible

Answer (score -1):

> My question now is: According to the javadoc, the constructor of the Area-class should be able to take a Shape-object, which Polygon is (it extends Shape). How do I correctly initialize an Area-object?

Isn't your solution right here? If what you state is true, you should simply be able to create it like so:

```
Area area = new Area(polygon);
```

Comment: Wrong: The constructor expects a parameter of type `com.sun.javafx.geom.Shape`, but `Polygon` extends `javafx.scene.shape.Shape`.

Comment: That's what i believed but it didn't work, that's why I was confused and wrote this question. answers are above